# can not open a file because of scandir

Tags: php

I'm trying to open a file with fopen(); but it does not work and when i click on the file i have an issue, apparently because of scandir :

"***Warning: scandir(C:\wamp64\www\acs\file_explorer_php\Start\text.txt): failed to open dir: No error in C:\wamp64\www\acs\file_explorer_php\explorator.php on line 45***"

My code so far, i create a folder "Start" if it does not exist.

This is the breadcrumbs :

```
  <?php

  $start ="Start";
  if(!is_dir($start)){
    mkdir($start);
  }

  if(!isset($_POST['cwd'])){
      $directory = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $start;
  }else {
    $directory = $_POST['cwd'];
  }

  $contentDirectory = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $directory);
  $path = "";


              echo "<form method='post' id='ch_cwd'> </form>";
              foreach($contentDirectory as $content){
                $path .= $content . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                if(strstr($path,$start)){
                    echo "<button type='submit' name='cwd' form='ch_cwd' value='" . substr($path, 0, -1) . "' class='breadcrumb-item'> " . $content . "</button>";
                }
              }
             ?>
```

and this is the code that display the files and folders :

```
  <?php
        echo "<br>";
        $dir = scandir($directory);
        //print_r($dir);
        foreach( $dir as $item){
          if($item !== "." && $item !== ".."){
            if($item[0] === "."){
              echo "";
            }
            elseif(is_dir($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item)){
              echo "<button type='submit' name='cwd' form='ch_cwd' value='" . $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item . "' class='d-inline-block pr-4'> " . "<i class='fas fa-folder-open fa-4x pt-2 pb-2 pr-2 text-primary'></i>". $item . "</button>";
            }
            else{
              echo "<button type='submit' name='cwd' form='ch_cwd' value='" . $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item . "' class='d-inline-block pr-4'> " . "<i class='fas fa-file fa-4x pt-2 pb-2 pr-2 text-primary'></i>". $item . "</button>";
              if(isset($_POST['pwd'])){
                $file = $_POST['pwd'];
                $openFile = fopen($file, "r");
                echo fread($openfile, filesize($item));

              }
            }

          }
        }
```

if the file is clicked, i want to read it. I don't know how to fix this issue or what's going on, if someone can help me and explain to me why scandir gives an error when i click on the file that i want to open.

Comment: According to the error message, you seem to be passing a path to a file instead of a directory to `scandir()`.

Comment: ok thanks, you were right, i correct it, i dont have the issue anymore :)